# Why was Villagulio angry at Muginami for taking the Vox in season 1 of Rinne no Lagrange?

Tags: rinne-no-lagrange

I am curious as to why Villagulio was angry at Muginami for taking the Vox in the first season. The scenes after that hint that Villagulio was forced to do so, but it didn't say why.

[Villagulio](http://lagrange-the-flower-of-rinne.wikia.com/wiki/Villagulio) article on the anime's wiki says that he did so in order for Muginami to get close to the others:

> Soon after, he formed the rebellious organization "Kiss" and sent Muginami to Kamogawa to investigate about the Voxes, **but apparently gets angry at her for becoming the pilot of Vox Ignis and abandons her, while actually it was part of his plan to have her get close to Madoka and the others.**

However, the wiki doesn't look that trustworthy to me.